# Moving Servers: Can I simply move the SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2

I'm in the process of moving between 2 servers. On the first server, I generated the .key certificate, and submitted the csr code to buy the certificates from Comodo.

Comodo gave me the chain file and the certificate, which I installed on the 1st server.

Now, I'm moving to another server, and my question is:
Since I've not generated the .key file on the 2nd server, will my SSL work if I simply copy and paste the 3 certificate files from server 1 to server 2?

Or do I need to generate key file with the 2nd server, then buy the certificate for the 2nd server again?

EDIT:
The certificate is for the domain, I've set up the hosted zone on AWS, and the last step is to simply change the name servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can move or copy certificates without issue. You'll need the key and certificate chain.

Answer (score 3):

Certificates are associated with hostnames.  If the hostname is moving so can the cert.  If the hostname is not moving then you need to get a new cert for the new hostname.

Comment: The ip is changing, which belongs to the host, but the domainname remains the same

Comment: The IP is not in the certificate and you can change that at will within TTL limits.